# Images appearing black in gridview when displayed using ImageProvider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a grid view that displays images and titles, and it should function like a button. However, the problem is that the images I have used appear black for some reason, and I'm unsure why.
Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I guess that the problem is I have used ImageProvider in the class Choice and used ImageIcon to display it as I am not able to display it using the ImageProvider it gives an error:
The argument type 'ImageProvider' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

Here is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.indigo),
          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.montserrat().fontFamily,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Moon Time'),
          ),
          body: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 1,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            children: List.generate(
              choices.length,
              (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: SelectCard(choice: choices[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({required this.title, required this.icon});
  final String title;
  final ImageProvider icon;
}

Image hygiene = Image.asset('assets/Images/hygiene.png');
Image foods = Image.asset('assets/Images/food.png');
Image mental = Image.asset('assets/Images/mental_health.png');
Image physical = Image.asset('assets/Images/physical_health.png');
Image track = Image.asset('assets/Images/tracking_n_planning.png');
Image help = Image.asset('assets/Images/professional_help.png');


List<Choice> choices = <Choice>[
  Choice(title: 'Hygiene', icon: hygiene.image),
  Choice(title: 'Food', icon: food.image),
  Choice(title: 'Mental Health', icon: mental.image),
  Choice(title: 'Physical Health', icon: physical.image),
  Choice(title: 'Tracking and Planning', icon: track.image),
  Choice(title: 'Professional Help', icon: help.image),
];

class SelectCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectCard({Key? key, required this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: () {
          print('Tapped');
        },
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: ImageIcon(
              choice.icon,
              size: 300.0,
            )),
            Text(choice.title),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```